# Full Screen Selection List, such as when selecting a ringtone or notification sound

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I want to display a list of options in a modal popup just like some apps let you click a button and then present you with a list of possible options.  This list takes up the entire screen, such as when selecting a ringtone or notification sound.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modal popup would reflect the exact same thing as a AlertDialog.Builder . This dialog is basically a popup where the user makes a decision and off it goes. You can have a click listener to do something when a button on the dialog is clicked.

This should help you find what kind you want:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html